PCP without reading the statement
The PCP theorem (very imprecisely!) states that for every $x\in L\in NP$ there is a polynomial witness $w$ such that for some random algorithm it is enough to read a constant number of bits of $w$ to verify $x\in L$.
But all the statements of the PCP theorem that I have found say nothing about how much of $x$ we need to read.
Doesn't it also follow from known proofs that it is also sufficient to read a constant number of bits from $x$?
Admittedly, I'm a very lazy reviewer; it's not just that I don't want to read the proof, I don't even want to read the statement!
Update. Now I see a very simple reason why this cannot be possible. Assume that $x\in L$ but if we flip any of its bits, then its not. Denote one such input by $x'$. Denote the witness for $x$ by $w$. Then $(x',w)$ will be also accepted unless the flipped bit of $x'$ is read, but if we only read a constant part of $x$, then chances for this are small.

in PCP you need to propagate error locally in x if any error exists, so you need entire x not constant fraction of x!

@Mohsen I don't really understand your logic. I'm not checking only constantly many bits from $x$, I also check a constant number of bits from $w$.

it seems that you cannot even do a polynomial time computable encoding of the input into an error correcting code that one would only need to read a const number of bits, iiuc.

In the standard definition of a PCP, the verifier reads the entire input $x$. Nevertheless, there is a variant of a PCP, called a "PCP of Proximity" (PCPP) or an "assignment tester", which also reads only a constant number of $x$. The price, however, is that a PCPP cannot tell whether $x \in L$ - it can only tell if $x$ is close to $L$ or not (in Hamming distance).
You can find more details in the relevant chapters of the Arora-Barak book or Goldreich's complexity book.

but what's the answer to the question of whether you can get away with only reading a constant number of bits from $x$?

Here are some lecture notes that came up by a simple searc for PCP of proximity. https://home.ttic.edu/~prahladh/teaching/07autumn/lectures/lec5.pdf.
